# Query filter for address in django

Tags: python, django, search, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have an SQL database that contains a table of places that have the following columns: address, city, zip, state

So is there a django package or a way to simply take ANY query a user might input into the search text box and parse the individual parts? like I type an address with a zip code so in the django backend I'd have to parse the address and the zip code. Is there a package that can do this? or Can someone give a general algorithm that might be used with django filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using django Q, just past the search text like :

### Search.html

```
...
  <form method='GET' action=''>
   <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter keywords">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>
...
```

### Views.py

```
from django.db.models import Q
def searchPlace(request):
    places = Places.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
         places = places.filter(
                            Q(address__icontains=query) |
                            Q(city__icontains=query) |
                            Q(zip__icontains=query) |
                            Q(state__icontains=query) |
                            ).distinct()

    return render(request, 'Search.html', {'places':places})
```

But this would search all the columns for match. Like ,if you type 'New' in your query it would give you all the values e.g. the ones with city ="New York", "New Jersey", adress = "New adress","New York st." etc.

[**Documentation**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: great answer :)